# Accessing 2D javascript array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to code a simple piece of javascript that reads in a CSV (pasted into a textarea on a webpage) and generates SQL insert statements but I keep getting undefined values when I reference the 2D array..

Please help!

```
var ret = "";
//alert("called");
//split the textarea into rows of text
var lines = text.split("\n");           
//the first line of text is the table name
var table = lines[0];                   

//the second line of text is an array of the attribute names
var attrnames = lines[1].split(",");        
var values = new Array();

//create a new array for each attribute
for (var i = 0; i < attrnames.length; i++) {
    //the length of each array is the total number of rows 
    //of text - 2 (title row and attr row)
    values.push(new Array(lines.length - 2));       
} 

//for each subsequent row, push the values to the appropriate arrays
for (var i = 2; i < lines.length; i++) {
    //get the current row (value, value, value, value)
    var thisrow = lines[i].split(",");          
    for (var j = 0; j < attrnames.length; j++) {
        //add the j-th attribute (thisrow[j]) to its array (values[j])
        values[j].push(thisrow[j]);             
    }   
}

var insertIntoTable = "";
var tableName = "";
var attrList = "";
var valueList = "";
var lead = "";

//loop through each row
for (var k = 2; k < lines.length; k++) {

    // --- ONE STATEMENT ---
    //create the statements
    insertIntoTable = "insert into table `";
    tableName = table;
    attrList = "` (";
    valueList = "(";
    for (var i = 0; i < attrnames.length; i++){
        attrList += "`" + attrnames[i] + "`,";
    }

    //trim the last comma, then add the closing parenthesis.
    attrList = attrList.substring(0, attrList.length-1) + ") ";
    lead = insertIntoTable + tableName + attrList;      

    for (var i = 0; i < attrnames.length; i++) {
        //this always points to undefined
        valueList += "'" + values[i][k-2] + "', "; 
    }   

    lead += (" values " + valueList);
    lead = lead.substring(0, lead.length-2) + ");\n";   

    ret += lead;

}

alert(ret);
```

Comment: don't paste the csv into a textbox, have them upload it through a file attachment

Comment: Isn't this where someone pastes a link to little Bobby Tables?

Comment: FWIW, this question *is not* about his SQL code, though all the usual caveat emptors should be given to OP.

Comment: Does your DBMS not have a CSV import tool?

Comment: I Know the inserts are gross. This is more of a nice utility to have on hand. I have a Java version of this script that reads and writes from/to files, and I just wanted a lighter version that I could use easily. Everywhere I've looked says to reference 2D js arrays arrayName[x][y], but for some reason mine isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript you do not need to set the length of arrays. They are more like ArrayLists or something; read more at [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

When you do

```
var x = new Array(10); // array with "length" set to 10
x.push("somevalue");
```

then the value will be inserted at `x[10]` - at the end of the list. Log it in the console to see it yourself.

So either you drop the `push()` and use absolute indizes instead, or initialize the array as empty - best with the [array literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals): `[]`. The relevant area of your code should then look like this:

```
//create a new empty array for each attribute
for(var i = 0; i<attrnames.length; i++){
    values.push([]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making an array of length `n`, where `n` is the number of rows, and **then** you are pushing on `n` more elements of data. Start with 0 length arrays and you will be fine:

```
//create a new array for each attribute
for(var i = 0; i<attrnames.length; i++){
    values.push(new Array(0));   // or '[]' -> the length of each array **will be** the total number of rows of text-2 (title row and attr row)
}
```

I would add caution that pasted data will be prone to lots of errors and potential security issues, such as SQL injection attacks.  Aside from that, what happens if you have extra `\n`s at the end of your data?  You will end up with more undefined data.